# Third party library management in a microservice architecture

Tags: microservices, dependency-management

We are moving our monolith to the microservices, and we are looking for a best practice regarding managing third party libraries, e.g: easy update in the case of security problems and so on.
It is clear that the microservices should be independent of each other, still this kind of unity in managing third party libraries would be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what third party libraries do.

You have some options:

- Include the library on your ms if the library is not updated frequently.
- Create a new microservice that offers the library functionality. This microservice could be installed as other microservice (on a new pod) or using the sidecar pattern.

For instance, we had a validation library developed to be used with Spring Boot microservices. There was a new customer requirement: we want to develop microservices with other languages. So what we did was create a new microservice that included the validation library and that new microservice was deployed as a sidecar. The requests were validated with this microservice before entering the real microservice with the customer logic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).